# compare two datasets and place values in a new dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I m working on ASP.NET using C#, 
i need to compare the data from two DataSets with a "ID" which is in both the DataSets and then add all the matching rows to a New dataset.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this on your own? What difficulty are you having? Or are you wanting us to give you a full blown solution, having done no research?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a DataRelation between the the tables in each DataSet, then use the GetChildRows method to find the matches which you could then add to your new DataSet or any other data structure. See [Introduction to DataRelation Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k21zcyx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by intersection of two datatables

```
using System.Data;

public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> Intersect(this DataTable table, DataTable other)
    {
        return table.AsEnumerable().Intersect(other.AsEnumerable());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> Intersect(this DataTable table, DataTable other, IEqualityComparer<DataRow> comparer)
    {
        return table.AsEnumerable().Intersect(other.AsEnumerable(), comparer);
    }
}
```

This is a [`shameless port of an elegant solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485306/finding-the-intersection-of-two-net-datatables/485338#485338) :)

Suppose you have two datasets set1 and set2 which you wanna compare. Do this

```
var newtable = set1.Tables[0].Intersect(set2.Tables[0]).CopyToDataTable();
```

Post more details, if this is not what you want.

Comment: how does this helps?  how intersect defines the row relation?

Comment: " i need to compare the data from two DataSets with a "ID" which is in both the DataSets"thats intersection if the schemas are same.