# Display message when new data row is added

Tags: c#

I'm a student and I'm new to C#.  I'm trying to create a program for a rural hospital that will query a radiology PACS system and display a message when a new scan arrives.

THIS IS HOW IT WORKS:

1)  The user runs a query by clicking the query button in the form

2)  It queries the PACS server and displays all the pending scans as data in a table.  (See code below)

3)  Each scan has it's own "accession number"

THIS IS WHERE I'M LOST:

I want to modify the form so when the user clicks the button named "QueryBtn" it checks to see if there are any new accession numbers that weren't in the previous query.  If there are new accession numbers, I want to display a message box that says "New Scan found"

I've been stuck on this for a long time, and would be willing to BUY LUNCH for anyone who could help me figure it out. :)

Thanks,

Jayden

(Anytime there is a new "Accession Number" in this table that was not listed in the previous query, I would like to have it display a messagebox)

//Here's where it adds data to the table:

```
    private void LoadResultsToGrid(DCXOBJIterator it)
    {
        DCXOBJ currObj = null;

        try
        {
            DataTable rq = new DataTable("RQ");
            DataRow rqRow;

            rq.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Patient Name", typeof(string)));
            rq.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Accession Number", typeof(string)));
            rq.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Requested Procedure ID", typeof(string)));
            rq.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Requested Procedure Description", typeof(string)));

            DataTable sps = new DataTable("SPS");
            DataRow spsRow;

            sps.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Requested Procedure ID", typeof(string)));
            sps.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Modality", typeof(string)));
            sps.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Scheduled Station AE Title", typeof(string)));
            sps.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Scheduled Procedure Step Description", typeof(string)));

            // Iterate over the query results
            for (; !it.AtEnd(); it.Next())
            {
                currObj = it.Get();
                rqRow = rq.NewRow();
                rqRow["Patient Name"] = 
                    TryGetString(currObj, DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.patientName);
                rqRow["Accession Number"] = 
                    TryGetString(currObj,DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.AccessionNumber);
                rqRow["Requested Procedure ID"] = 
                    TryGetString(currObj,DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.RequestedProcedureID);
                rqRow["Requested Procedure Description"] = 
                    TryGetString(currObj,DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.RequestedProcedureDescription);
                rq.Rows.Add(rqRow);
```

Here's the query button:

```
private void QueryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DCXOBJIterator it = null;
        DCXREQ req = null;
        DCXOBJ rp = null;
        DCXOBJ sps = null;
        DCXELM el = null;
        DCXOBJIterator spsIt = null;
        try
        {
            // Fill the query object
            rp = new DCXOBJ();
            sps = new DCXOBJ();
            el = new DCXELM();

            // Build the Scheduled procedure Step (SPS) item
            el.Init((int)DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.ScheduledStationAETitle);
            el.Value = StationNameEdit.Text;
            sps.insertElement(el);
```

Comment: Could you shorten down the code? There is quite a lot to read. Only post what _really matters_.

Comment: it is still not clear to go thu the code. So do you have the code which tells you that there is a new accession number? If yes, what's stopping you from showing the message? in case if you have more than one accession no, you can loop thru it and display the mess.

Comment: I apologize about that...no I don't have any code that tells me there is a  new accession number.  I would like to know maybe some suggestions as to how I could code that.  Maybe store the last query to a text file and compare it to the new query?

Comment: This is probably a useful question to consider:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485306/finding-the-intersection-of-two-net-datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is my understanding that every time you LoadResultsToGrid, you get all pending scans(the ones that you might already be displaying plusany new results, right?).

You can create a static list and keep a record of the AcessionNumbers you have already displayed.

```
private static List<String> AlreadyDisplayedAccessionNumber = new List<String>();
private static bool IsFirstLoad =true;
```

So in your for loop, right after:

```
rqRow["Accession Number"] = TryGetString(currObj,DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.AccessionNumber);
```

you will check to see whether this accession number has already been displayed

```
    if(!AlreadyDisplayedAccessionNumber.Contains(TryGetString(currObj,DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.AccessionNumber)))
{
//do not display this message if we are loading the details first time round
if(!IsFirstLoad) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("New scan found"); 
}
    AlreadyDisplayedAccessionNumber.Add(TryGetString(currObj,DICOM_TAGS_ENUM.AccessionNumber);//add to our list this new accession number which we have just reported it as new, in order not to report it again as new

}
```

And right at the end of your method  LoadResultsToGrid

```
private void LoadResultsToGrid(DCXOBJIterator it)
{
   //all your code for loading here
   IsFirstLoad=false; //set this to false, we have just load the results for the first time
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Wow that worked great!  Do you think there would be anyway I could have it not display the message "New Scan found" when the table loads for the first time? Would you recommend just adding another if statement that doesn't display the message box if the AlreadyDisplayedAccessionNumber list is null?

Comment: you wont be able to check that in the AlreadyDisplayedAccessionNumber list property. for that you should create a new property

private static bool IsFirstLoad = true; , then in your LoadResultsToGrid method, right at the end, you set this to false,
IsFirstLoad=false;

Now all you need to do before you display the message is to check the IsFirstLoad property, thus if it is false (this is not the first load, then display the message)
If (!IsFirstLoad){ MessageBox.Show("New scan found"); }

Comment: I have edited the answer with the new requirements. Be sure to understand what the code is doing. Think about why you wouldn't be able to use just the list to check whether to display the message during the first round, the best way will be to implement it and see what the problems are. Good luck